# Give SwiftUI Text view a fixed width and only make Text view bottom grow when text wraps

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my first example, I have text that is placed at a specific position on screen. In the second example, when I add more characters, the text increases in height in both directions from top and bottom. Is there anyway for the text view to grow in height but only by affecting the bottom portion of the view?

**First Example**
[image]

**Second Example**
[image]

Here is my code for this Text view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // ZStack is used for a background color
        ZStack {
            Color.teal.opacity(0.3)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Image(.snareDrum)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.80, height: proxy.size.height * 0.80)
                    .background {
                        Color.white
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus.")
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .frame(width: 200)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .background(.red)
                .position(x: 195, y: 210)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `ZStack` default alignment is `center`, you should turn that into `topLeading` which is `(0, 0)` and use something like `offset` to move the text where you need to like:

```
ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {  //  add this
    ,,,

    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus.")
        .lineLimit(nil)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .frame(width: 200)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .background(.red)
        .offset(x: 195, y: 210) //  use this
//        .position(x: 195, y: 210) //  remove this
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for the help. I actually do need the position to be available because will have JSON values that will dictate X & Y values for Text view placement.

Comment: I have updated the answer according to the `dictate X & Y` rule. @MiguelTepale

Comment: Hmm, looks like coordinate placement is dependent based on its alignment. I may have to rework this Text view logic since we want to place the Text view based on the parent's view coordinate plane. @MojtabaHosseini